# A syntax independent theory of categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, foundations

The classic way to encounter the theory of categories is via Set Theory via the typical definition we see for categories. We see all kinds of categories that are equivalent to the category of small categories. I wonder about presentations of the theory of categories. Is there any work done on cataloguing the various presentations. To facilitate an answer we may need to define a presentation of the theory. It may consist of a logical language or even the standard presentations of algebraic structures. For instance, a presentation of the theory of partial monoids would count as a presentation of Categories. The presentation should come with enough structure to analyze all small Categories.

What I am really looking for more is something like a syntax independent theory of categories.  For instance, I had a thought a while ago about monads and string diagrams.  Awodey puts forth monads as syntax independent theories (Awodey, Category Theory 2006).  I am likely misreading this, or reading too much into it, but in his chapter on monads he states "...it turns out that every adjunction describes, in a "syntax invariant" way, a notion of an "algebra" for an abstract "equational theory".  This is just about all he says.  The way I see it, we are not using a logical language when presenting an algebra with either an adjunction or the monad it generates.  You might say that string diagrams have a syntax, since string actions are equivalent to various algebraic axioms, but that is not very precise.

Then, I saw Marsden  put together a [presentation of categories in terms of string diagrams.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.7220)

I like to think that string diagrams can be seen as containers.  [This is a paper about containers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.5809).  So the idea is that you have a (co)monad that encodes the container for the theory of categories.  That is more what I would say is a syntax independent theory of Categories.  I am not sure how this would relate to all presentations of the theory of categories.

Comment: Can you give a link for that Awodey claim? It seems to me that's the only thing that would help me know what "syntax-independent" means here.

Comment: It's in his this text book.  I will link it.

Comment: Since I don't have that book, and I'm not sure it's electronically available, maybe you should summarise the presentation and explain why (or quote Awodey explaining why) it should be considered syntax-independent. This is just part of writing a self-contained question.

Comment: See Hyland, Power, _The Category Theoretic Understanding of
Universal Algebra: Lawvere Theories and
Monads_ - https://doi.org/10.1016/j.entcs.2007.02.019

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking you probably want to look at _sketches_, since these are ways of presenting the analogue of Lawvere theories that work for defining small categories (equational theories/Lawvere theories aren't sufficient, due to the partially-defined composition on the set of all arrows).

Comment: For future reference, I would have recommended asking what Awodey means here and for references to more about that, before asking if it would fit the thing you are thinking about. If it were suitable, you have to understand about what he is talking about in a more in-depth way than the passing reference; as it is not suitable, you still learn something useful, but you could have seen *why* it's not appropriate. It's taken two questions, a now-deleted answer and a more than one comment discussion to get to the point where we are getting the references you need (in François' and my comments).

Comment: See also the references at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/syntax-semantics+duality.